# How to get a value from [String:[String:String]]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

So I have an array of elements

```
    var myArray: [String:[String:String]] = [
        "firstElement":["userId":"linkId"],
        "secondElement":["user_Id":"link_Id"],
        "thirdElement":["userId":"linkId"]
    ]
```

To get the first element is all clear, just use myArray.keys, what about the array in array elements? How to get firstElement -> userId and linkId?

Comment: There are no arrays here. `myArray` is a dictionary of string and dictionaries. You're probably doing something wrong if you are using such a nested type. How about creating structs/classes for whatever data you are trying to work with?

Comment: Regarding [dictionaries](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID113)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was commented, you're only using dictionaries here, not arrays. There is no concept of a "first element" in a dictionary as it is an unordered collection.

If you want all the values in the dictionary, you can use myArray.values. If you need an **ordered** key-value pairs, you can use the type KeyValuePairs, although it's *highly* unlikely you actually need this.

You may consider reviewing the collection types in swift: [Swift Collections](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID113)

If you don't want to create a struct for the (userId, linkId) data, then you can consider using a tuple instead.

```
var userLinks = [(userId: String, linkId: String)]()
```